# Global and local variable issue

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local

```
var element = document.getElementById('image1');

function leftArrowPressed () {
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}
```

The code is for moving images with arrow keys. When `element` is a global variable it doesn't work but works when it's a local variable. Why?

Comment: A side questio to your current posted code: Why don't you pass the variable element as an argument in your function `leftArrowPressed()`?

Comment: Could you show me how?

Comment: `function leftArrowPressed(anObject){anObject.style.left = parseInt(anObject.style.left) - 5 + 'px';} leftArrowPressed(element);`

Comment: It Doesn't work. I already tried that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And have you also read the answer from @StanislavMayorow ?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any problems with scope.

I don't see all code. I guess that a problem in this line because it's called when DOM element doesn't exist.

```
var element = document.getElementById("image1");
```

Try to use `window.onload`.